# How can I create a Factory of TransparentUpgradeableProxy?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, delegatecall, proxy-contracts, factory

I have the following code for a Factory that creates instances of a contract that is **Upgradeable**. I understand that, in order to achieve this, one of the options I have is to use `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` (actually, when I first deployed using `Hardhat` -and it worked- this is what it was done under the hood):

**SmartWalletFactory.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "../multiwrap/SmartWallet.sol";
import "../proxy/SmartWalletProxy.sol";

contract SmartWalletFactory {
    mapping(uint256 => address) private smartWallets;
    SmartWalletProxy immutable proxy;

    constructor(address _initialImpl) {
        proxy = new SmartWalletProxy(_initialImpl);
    }

    function createSmartWallet(
        uint256 _smartWalletId,
        address _defaultAdmin,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _contractURI,
        address[] memory _trustedForwarders,
        address _royaltyRecipient,
        uint256 _royaltyBps
      ) public {
        TransparentUpgradeableProxy smartWallet = new TransparentUpgradeableProxy(address(proxy), address(0), abi.encodeWithSelector(SmartWallet(payable(address(0))).initialize.selector, _defaultAdmin, _name, _symbol, _contractURI, _trustedForwarders, _royaltyRecipient, _royaltyBps));
        smartWallets[_smartWalletId] = address(smartWallet);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the proxy:

**SmartWalletProxy.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/BeaconProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/UpgradeableBeacon.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol";

contract SmartWalletProxy is Ownable {
    TransparentUpgradeableProxy immutable proxy;
    address public smartWalletImplementation;

    constructor(address _initialImpl) {
        proxy = new TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_initialImpl, address(0), "0x");
        smartWalletImplementation = _initialImpl;
        transferOwnership(tx.origin);
    }

    function upgrade(address _newImpl) public onlyOwner {
        proxy.upgradeTo(_newImpl);
        smartWalletImplementation = _newImpl;
    }

}
```

So I first deploy `SmartWallet` as my implementation contract and then I want to deploy the `SmartWalletFactory` using the address of `SmartWallet` as input.

The problem I am having is that I am getting the following error (using `Remix`):

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"code": 3,
"message": "execution reverted: Address: low-level delegate call failed",
"data": "0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027416464726573733a206c6f772d6c6576656c2064656c65676174652063616c6c206661696c656400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Does anybody know what this error could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for, but I would **STRONGLY** advise you consider using the **UUPS** design pattern for an upgradable smart contract implementation. It's similar to the `transparent proxy pattern`, except the upgrade is triggered via the **logic contract** rather than from the **proxy contract**.

[UUPS proxy pattern tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-uups-proxy-pattern-upgrade-smart-contracts/)

The advantages are many. For example, there is no possibility of `solidity function collision` or any exploit based on that. Plus `Hardhat` && `OpenZepplein` both offer full library support for it.

In my **personal** opinion, `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` is outdated. **UUPS** && **Dimond pattern** are the only two worth considering.

Comment: Thank you, now I am using UUPS proxy. Anyway, I am getting the same error. But I do think this proxy is better than the one I was using before.

Comment: It would be nice if you can point me to an actual Factory or Clone implementation of an upgreadeable smart contract that uses this kind of proxy. I found none looking online. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, but if you are getting the same error,  I would like to see your code, and I try to fix it. Would be possible for you to share the code?

Comment: This is what I have at the moment: https://gist.github.com/MatiFalcone/c0f6c5c82a59d8628160a5a9e372ccc4

It is based in this solution that works, but with a Token contract which is not as complex as the one I have: https://github.com/MatiFalcone/ContractFactoryUpgradeable

Right now problem is that when I want to createSmartWallet from the Factory contract, the Factory has not the right permissions to mint the NFT. I don't know how to fix this since I first deploy the Smart Wallet and then using that I deploy the Factory. Is not possible to know the address of the Factory beforehand.

Comment: Alright,  I understand. Is this urgent for you? Because I am on hollidays now, but I could sit down and give you an answer in a few days. That alright by you?

Comment: @FalconStakepool from what I have seen in your code. I would have just used Factory + SmartWallet contract. You first deploy Factory, and then it creates upgradable SmartWallets. There is no need for SmartWallet proxy. The proxy functionality is handed by UUPS. (I know this can seem confusing,  but please take another look at the tutorial I posted). It actually makes your life easier,  because you don't have to worry/implement proxy.

Comment: Yes, no worries, of course enjoy your holidays! I will look at the tutorial again. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The [second parameter](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/49c0e4370d0cc50ea6090709e3835a3091e33ee2/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol#L36) of `TransparentUpgradeableProxy` sets the proxy admin address. When initializing `proxy` in the first line of the constructor of `SmartWalletProxy.sol`, you're specifying the zero address as the admin of your proxy. Perhaps try `address(this)` instead of `address(0)`.

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the transparent proxy pattern, you have to operate the proxy using a `proxyAdmin`. When any interaction with your proxy contract is made, the proxy delegates the call to whichever contract you have provided a proxy for.

So, the clue here is the error line `"message": "execution reverted: Address: low-level delegate call failed"`. Just reading this, I would assume that you haven't set up your `proxyAdmin` **or** that you are calling the contract from a non-admin address.

Read the docs [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies) from OpenZeppelin

Comment: I have replaced that line but I am getting the same error.

Comment: You say that now you’re using UUPS - is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Try passing `msg.sender` as the address argument in the constructor (`address(this)` won' work as that would represent the contract itself being it's own admin, and the delegate call would throw an error. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

as you're facing issue with upgradeable contracts. I would suggest you to use UUPS EIP-1967 contract on remix. Remix gives you full support of UUPS. Just you need to use openzeppelin wizard to get useful UUPS inheritences and use it in remix.

Comment: Thank you, now I am using UUPS proxy. Anyway, I am getting the same error. But I do think this proxy is better than the one I was using before.